# How to count packet using scapy

Tags: python, scapy

I have problem with count new packet in scapy. That means I try count every packet which is sniff. I wrote it this way but in output I had new packet and there is always one below him.

My current code is:

```
def print_packet(packet):
    count = 0
    ip_layer = packet.getlayer(IP)
    print("[!] New Packet: {src} -> {dst}".format(src=ip_layer.src, dst=ip_layer.dst))
    count += 1
    print(count)

print("[*] Start sniffing...")
sniff(iface=interface, filter="ip", prn=print_packet)
print("[*] Stop sniffing"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `count` variable is local to the `print_packet` function. You should instead have global `count` defined outside of that function.

```
count = 0

def print_packet(packet):
    global count
    ip_layer = packet.getlayer(IP)
    print("[!] New Packet: {src} -> {dst}".format(src=ip_layer.src, 
              dst=ip_layer.dst))
    count += 1
    print(count)

print("[*] Start sniffing...")
sniff(iface=interface, filter="ip", prn=print_packet)
print("[*] Stop sniffing")
```